# Rails ActiveSupport::TestCase - colourful output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, minitest

Surprisingly, I didn't find the standard way to make the output of Rails Minitest colorful. There're some workarounds, though.

So what's the way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Add [minitest-rg](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rg) to the test group in your `Gemfile`:

```
group :test do
  gem "minitest-rg"
end
```

Then require `minitest/rg` in your `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
require "minitest/rg"
```

Now you have colorful test output when running `rake test`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, in this [rakefile](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/Rakefile#L16) change it to:

```
namespace :test do
  task :isolated do
    Dir.glob("test/**/*_test.rb").all? do |file|
      sh(Gem.ruby, '-w', '-Ilib:test', file, '-p')
    end or raise "Failures"
  end
end
```

Then from the console run `rake test:isolated` while in activesupport folder and watch the rainbow go!  This is using minitests built in pride library for color.